# can't call sweetAlert as onClick, style sheet loaded on page but not inside button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert

Okay so I'm trying to replace my javaScript alerts as sweetAlerts but it appears the style sheets will not load with an onClick event unless I put them directly above said button. Let me explain.

So in my base.html file I am importing the css and java for bootstrap sweet Alert as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/sweetalert.css" %}"/>
<script src="{% static "js/sweetalert.min.js" %}"></script>
```

these are both downloaded directly from bootstrap sweet Alert.

I then have an html file that extends base.html. Within that file I can call:`<script>sweetAlert('', 'Hi)</script>` and said sweetAlert will appear on page load.

However whenever I try to call it as an onClick:`<button onClick="sweetAlert('', 'Hi)"></button>` It does nothing unless I put the css and js links directly above said button like such:

```
<script src="http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/lib/sweet-alert.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/lib/sweet-alert.css">
<button onclick="sweetAlert('', 'hi');"></button>
```

with the above code the sweetAlert displays fine, otherwise it doesn't do anything to display at all. The css and js does appear to be linked to the page as I can have a sweetAlert appear on the page on page load but as soon as I add it to a button on click event everything goes bad.

Very confused, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery.min.js was being linked twice in the base.html file